# Populating a JqGrid with Json data from an ASMX

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a JqGrid that a i want to populate with Json data that is served by an ASMX web service.
Tha ajax call to get the data should be made based on info entered by user in a form. How i can configure jqgrid to do that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calling ASMX from JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery) post on SO should do it for you.

Have you looked at this [documentation](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm)??

Comment: I can return Json data from an ASMX, but i do not known how to bind it to the jqGrid.

Comment: updated the reply with link to documentation. examples are in php/cf but you need to take it from the place where you get the JSON