# How do I run my code without having the page refresh?

Tags: c#, web-applications, webforms

I have a button on a web form and when I click it my code executes but in order for any changes to occur the page has to refresh itself. How do I make the changes happen without a refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably have to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Since you're using asp.net webforms, you could most easily place the code needed to be updated asynchronously into an `UpdatePanel`

Slightly more challenging, but more robust, you could also put your code into web services (or static page methods, I believe) and then use `jQuery` to call them, and use the results from them to update your dom.

Just one small note on the jQuery option, since, as another answerer has noted, I could be typing all day, make sure you don't use dom ids to select your dom elements for update, since asp.net messes with the ids that are actually generated (unless you're using asp.net 4, where this is configurable)

[jQuery homepage](http://jquery.org/)

[UpdatePanel Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102853/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102407-1.aspx)

[Question on calling asmx with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Its called [AJAX](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/). JavaScripts on the client contact the page, often reading data to update the HTML-page. For instance for a progress indicator to update.

Just set up a timer on the page and do whatever required in the server codebehind.

For some tutorials on how to get started look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257110/ajax-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Regular asp.net web forms are dependent on the post back cycle of web. You'll need to use some AJAX (asynchronous javascript and xml) controls in order to get some actions to occur asynchronously on your web page. Google for ASP.NET AJAX and you'll find what you're looking for. Here are some links to get you started:

[Download Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx)

[Tutorial](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/)