# Populating Controls via AJAX from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have some JavaScript that displays a `<div>` as a modal dialog. This is working fine, but now I'd like to populate some controls on that `<div>` using AJAX. I'm trying to determine the best way to utilize AJAX from the JavaScript.

I know that I can call `__doPostBack()` from JavaScript to initiate the AJAX postback. But then I have to resort to tricks such as injecting some startup script in order to display the modal `<div>` from JavaScript after the controls have been populated.

Is there a better way?

Comment: May not be relevant but you should look into something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) >= JavaScript+AJAX

Comment: @Pablo: jQuery is available to me, but I don't know how it would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to leverage ASP.NET controls, you can make an ajax call to a service that instantiates your control, populates it, renders it, and returns the rendered HTML to your javascript/ajax function.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm fairly new to jQuery and don't know how to do that.

Comment: This should get you going. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery