# Strange response from .NET backend after Ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, extjs

I'm trying to get familiar with ASP .net so after 'hello world' I was trying to add some simple backend request handling. So I'm doing an Ajax request from my page to the asp page :

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://http://localhost:49852/Default.aspx',
        params: {
            html        : {'array': document.body.innerHTML}
        },
        success : function(response){
        console.log('RESPONSE !', response);
            //me.onSuccess(response, callback, errback);
        },
        failure : function(response){
            console.log('RESPONSE FAIL !', response);
        }
    });
```

And this is my page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

And the code that's behind it (I'm not sure if the structure should look like this, but I wasn't able to find any example of requests handling without forms used) :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (this.Request["html"] != null){
            this.Response.Write("{'success': true, 'msg': 'Its working'}");
       }
        else{
            this.Response.Write("{'success': false, 'msg': 'Error in request data.'}");
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I go to this address in my browser, I'm getting the proper (false) text displayed. But when I'm trying with XHR request, I can't see any request in the Firebug console at all, and in the Net tab I get 'OPTIONS' response :

[image]

which looks as follows when logged to console :

[image]

Any ideas what's goin on here ?

Comment: Have you tried using a `WebService` marked with `[SciptService]` instead of a `Page`?

Comment: any links ? It's my first day with .net so I'm knees deep in examples, demos and docs :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery for a few examples.

Comment: try setting this attribute over your requested method: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

Comment: Your version of .Net will make a difference on some of this, much easier with 4.0+

Comment: It might just be my coffee but I see double here in your code :) `'http://http://` - and for what its worth, the webservice is the way to go on ajax stuff.

Comment: This might give you a walkthrough http://patrickjarfish.com/blog/?p=61

Comment: Another option is HttpHandler, this is my favorite method.

Comment: @jrummel if you'll add your comments as an answer I can mark it as the proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`WebService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx) marked with [`SciptService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a Page.

Here's an example from MSDN:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string GetServerTime() 
    {
        string serverTime =
            String.Format("The current time is {0}.", DateTime.Now);

        return serverTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is wrong. It is:

```
http://http://localhost:49852/Default.aspx
```

When it should be:

```
http://localhost:49852/Default.aspx
```