# JQuery webservice call always in error

Tags: jquery

I have written a simple html page like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<form name="form">
      <input type="text" id="messageTest" name="msg" value="Your message"/>
      <input type="submit" id="login" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>     
    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.asmx/HelloWorld",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function(xhr,err){
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }, false);
</script>
</HTML>
```

It always return "readyState:0 status:0 responseText:undefined"
All my files are in the same folder.
This is my webservice :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Comment: what console.log(err); shows in console ?

Comment: It shows "error".

Comment: See this answer, it might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052049/1220550

Comment: The error handler is called with **three** parameters. Check the missing third one for an error message. And you're telling jQuery the server will response with JSON (`dataType: "json"`) but the server only returns `Hello World`

Comment: I have changed dataType: "json" to dataType: "text" and added a third parameter that shows "Access denied" in the console.

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can write `$("#login").click(function(e) {...})` instead of `document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(e) {...}`. Also, asmx is ancient. new development should use WCF or WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following before the ajax call :

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

I have loaded my webservice from visualstudio and changed the url to call and it is now working.