# How to use this asmx webservice with jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asmx

i have this webservice:
https://farmaciasdesimilares.com/WSAjaxHttps/MXFSWEBAJAXService.asmx/ObtenerProductosPorID

now, i want to show a list of the products that this service contain (ObtenerProductosPorId translate to GetProductsById), so i can show the products in a html page

i have been searching but cannot get a proper answer i know that this can be done with ajax, but i dont know how

im new to web design

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

[Calling ASMX from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery)

[Call (Consume) Web Service (ASMX) using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Do some more research via this Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=ajax%20to%20call%20asmx%20web%20service&oq=ajax%20to%20call%20asmx%20web%20service&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.19989.29183.0.29563.29.29.0.0.0.0.204.3135.2j22j1.25.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.25.3134...0j0i20k1j0i131k1.Nv3iGY1m7lw).