# Webservice returns Internal error 500 only in remote

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, web-services

I tried a web service + ajax call as written by [Fuxiang](https://forums.asp.net/t/1927064.aspx?WebService%20issue). I created the aspx page and the service (.asmx) and hosted it in the server in IIS. The code works perfectly when i run it in the local server.

When I call the same from a remote machine i get internal 500 error. Why is this so? The same happens when i try with angular instead of jquery ajax. What is the work around?

**ERROR**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) Request format is unrecognized for URL
>   unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.

Here's the code:

**aspx**

```
 <script>
        //no paras to call
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/text",
                url: "Test_WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                data: {},
                dataType: 'text',
                error: function (err) {
                    $('#content').html(err);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#content').html(result);
                    //  alert(result);
                }
            });

            $('#loading').ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
            }).ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });

    </script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="loading">
            service is handling，please wait......
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**asmx**

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Test_WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I have added the following in web config and it hasn't made a change:

```
 <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

I have registered the asp version in the web server, still it does not work

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regii‌​s -i
```

Comment: You cant ajax call that normally dear. to shorten the issue use this : https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Read [ask] and research that error message. Plenty of suggestions to fix it apart from that first one. You may also want to reconsider using ASMX, it's deprecated. Try WebAPI or WCF.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster! I have already used that link and tried all the solutions provided. Nothing worked. Moreover my context is different. My code works perfectly in the local machine. I am able to open the asmx in the remote machine. Once i club it with the angular js/ jquery ajax call this issue occurs. Wish you know a solution!

Comment: @Linda, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery

Comment: Your WebMethod doesn't accept any parameters and you are still trying to post empty object. Try GET method or change signature of HelloWorld method.